# How to pass a Pandas dataframe as argument to function through apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have a custom function as below to do something.

```
def f(x):
    x['A'] = '123'
    return x

df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(f)
```

Now, I would like to change the function as

```
def f(x):
    x['A'] = '123'
    df2['name'] = 'ABC'
    return x
```

How to pass the dataframe df2 as an argument to apply?

Does it work? `df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(f, args = df2)`

Answer (score 0):

`df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(f, args = df2)` - this will give an error ""TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'

correct solution: remove args and pass like this, it solves the error.

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(f, df2)
```